# Why does this piece of cloth collapse if I enable 'cloth collision'?

Tags: cloth-simulation, collision

I want the one piece to simulate as cloth, but it doesn't work.

If I don't check the "cloth collision", it works correctly. But if I check it, the one piece collapses.

I already tried to change some values on simulation tab but it didn't work well.

So please tell me what should I do?
I'm using blender 2.79b on Mac OS Catalina.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A trick that solves this issue most of the time is increasing the scale. Blender dont like small sized items in simulations for some reason.
Dont forget to apply the scale!

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!